# In SharePoint, how can the "Issue ID" column of an issues list be included in the detail form (DispForm.aspx) and/or alert emails?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

We've created a pretty standard issue tracking system based off of SharePoint's template with just a few extra columns.  On the list view (AllItems.aspx), the first column is called "Issue ID" and has a number.  Our developers and QC use that number in discussions.  However, that number doesn't seem to want to show up on the detail form (DispForm.aspx) nor in the alert email.

Can this field be included in at least one of these communication methods?  If so, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We did something similar and used workflow via SharePoint Designer to copy the ID field into a field called "Issue Number".  The workflow gets triggered automatically on Create / Edit (we included edit because the field can be modified by the user on the edit form and if that happens we want the number refreshed with the actual ID).

---

Before you create the workflow in SharePoint Designer, you need to add a column called "Issue Number" to the list you want to tweak.

1. List item
2. Open Sharepoint Designer
3. List item
4. Click File New -> Workflow
5. Give a name for the workflow
   a. select the list from the dropdown
   b. Uncheck Allow this workflow to be manually started and check automatically start on new and change then press Next
6. Give the step a name like "Assign Issue Number"
7. Create a Condition
   If Compare a field -> If Issue Number not equals Current_Item:ID
8. Create an Action
   Update List Item -> Set Issue Number to Current_Item:ID
9. Press Finished and test out by creating a new issue.

*The Issue Number will appear on the form and if you have emails setup to notify on assignment it will appear in the reassigned template.
*It will not appear in the created email confirmation because the workflow gets triggered after that email was executed.

Comment: +1 I've been on a team where this approach was used and it worked fine.

Comment: This sounds promising - as a bit of neophyte in this area, could you help with a bit of step-by-step through this?  I have SP Designer and I have opened the site and have drilled-down to the list in question.  Now what?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the extra info!  However, it appears that the particular site this list is on is WSS rather than MOSS and I don't have workflow available there.  Ah well.

Answer (score 1):

I just added the issue ID using a total of 4 characters.  Create a new column, set it to a Calculated column, in the formula type [ID].  Voila!  The ID is now in your detail view.

Comment: Well, maybe not.  It seems to bring over the Issue ID from *existing* records, but *new* ones created get "0".

Answer (score 0):

The ID link returned the for me, however, the work around which sufficed for me was to enter 'Created' in the Calculated Column formula and ensure it is set at date and time. That then creates a unique idenity (unless you receive more than 1 list update per minute) than can be viewed in the email alert message